# How to create contextual styling with styled components? (zero selector)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I would like to know if it's possible to create contextual styling, without any CSS Selector.

Something like:

```
<Button primary>
    <Text>BUTTON</Text> // if the button is primary then have 20px padding else 0
    <Icon/> // if the button is primary then have red background
</Button>
```

The reason I do not really want to use CSS for these are the fact I want to kinda share my components in React Native (where you do not have any selector, or css)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is the way to go. Not sure why you wouldn't want to use it.

```
button {
    padding: 0;
}

button[primary] {
    padding: 20px;
}

button[primary] icon {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you don't want to use CSS, perhaps specify your reason, and I might be able to improve on my answer.

Comment: Well, I would really go with the css way, but I kinda want to share these components with my RN codebase.